# How do I enable a popover after highlighting text?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, highlight, popover

I am trying to understand how rap genius enable the functionality where they enable a user to highlight and then show a popover after the highlighting is finished.  How would I do this using jquery?

If it helps, I'm also using twitter bootstrap for other items in my project including popovers after a user clicks on a button.

Edit: the first example works (where the user selects text within the input box), but the second (where the user selects the text in 'content') doesn't work.

```
    <p class = 'content'>
    Click and drag the mouse to select text in the inputs.
    </p>
    <input type="text" value="Some text" />
    <input type="text" value="to test on" />

    <div></div>


    <script>
      $(":input").select( function () {
      $("div").text("Something was selected").show().fadeOut(500);
      });

      $("content").select( function () {
      $("div").text("Something else outside of input was selected").show().fadeOut(5000);
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: Check mouseup event. That should give you an hint.

Comment: @HugoDozois I've added and update to the existing code.  Can it work with .select instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **JavaScript**

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").onmousedown = function(){
             //Client has pressed the mouse button without releasing it...
             this.onmouseup = function(){
                    document.getElementById("myPopUp").style.display="block";
             };
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tdynL/)

Using **JQuery**

```
$("#myDiv").mousedown(function(){

          $("#myDiv").mouseup(function(){

                     $("#myPopUp").show();
          });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/G7MK7/)

[**JQuery's .select()**](http://api.jquery.com/select/)

> **The select event is sent to an element when the user makes a text selection inside it. This event is limited to `input type="text"` fields and `textarea` boxes.**

Comment: I've added the code I have so far using .select.  The first example is working but the second one isn't...before I switch, is there a reason why the above isn't working?

Comment: @sharataka First error, `$(".content")` and not `$("content")`, second error, `.select()` will only work on `input` and `textarea`.